# Save each column of an Excel file in a separate text file

Tags: python, excel

I would like to save each column of an excel file in a separate text file.

For example..

```
ID, contents
1, aaa is bla bla bla
2, ccc is bla bla bla
```

I would like to save `1 aaa is bla bla bla` in `a.txt`
and save `2 ccc is blablabla` in `b.txt`.

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a Python question in here, the answer is likely to use [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) :-)

If it is an Excel question, there is a SaveAs option for "Tab Delimited Text (.txt)" and another for "Comma Separated Values (*.csv)".  Here is a step-by-step tutorial:  http://www.howtogeek.com/79991/convert-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file/

If you want to control Excel from Python and are on Windows, you can use the COM interface for the Win32API.  Here's a simple example: http://users.rcn.com/python/download/quoter.pyw

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks how to "save each column of an Excel file" but from your example, it looks like you really want to save each row in a separate file. Raymond has already suggested using the COM interface. Here's some code which worked for me:

```
import win32com.client

STARTROW = 2
ENDROW = 3

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False

workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\FULL\PATH\TO\EXCEL\FILE\HERE.xls")
sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

letter = 'a'
for row in xrange(STARTROW, ENDROW + 1):
    dest = open(letter + ".txt", 'w')
    dest.write("{0},{1}".format(sheet.Cells(row, 1).Text, sheet.Cells(row, 2).Text))
    dest.close()
    letter = chr(ord(letter)+1)

xl.Quit()
```

If there are more than 26 rows in your file, then you're going to need a better scheme for the destination file names.